# Is it possible run multiple angular applications in webworkers?

Tags: angular, web-worker

Is it possible to run simultaneously 2 angular app in different web worker?

Then I [experimented](https://github.com/shanhaichik/angular-workers-in-action) with run 1 application in the worker. Everything works fine.

I want to create a flexible structure and to load and run the desired application, depending on the condition of and addresses without reloading the page.

if the ui thread is already running angular app, then launch another in worker in trouble.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is it possible to do two separate things in two separate places? Yes. What exactly are you trying to do, though?

Comment: @msanford 

I want to make app Manager. Depending on the state or address to load and run the desired application in the worker without reloading the page.

And one app has to work constantly. 

That is, first application always works, and the second is dynamically loaded and started by.

I hope I could explain